# SQL Server 2012 SELECT max date based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I have a table with approximately 8 million rows. The rows contain an ID, a date, and an event code. I would like the select all the ID's and dates for which the event code is equal to 1 and there has been an event code equal to 2 at some time in the past.

For example, my table looks like this:

```
ID    Date       Code
----------------------
1     4/16/2016   6
1     4/10/2016   1
1     3/1/2016    13
1     1/26/2016   2
2     5/2/2016    8
2     3/14/2016   1
2     1/13/2016   14
```

I would want ID = 1 and Date = 4/10/2016 returned but I would not want anything returned with ID=2 because ID=2 never had an event code equal to 2.

How should I write my `SELECT` statement to get these results?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: You want `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Code = 1 AND`.... something  else

Comment: Can "1" appear more than one time for a given id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select the max date for each `ID`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE Code = 1
)
SELECT
    ID, Date, Code
FROM Cte c
WHERE
    rn = 1
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM tbl t
        WHERE
            t.ID = c.ID
            AND t.Date < c.Date
            AND t.Code = 2
    )
;
```

<kbd>[ONLINE DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/484165)</kbd>

---

Using `MAX`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
    ID, Date = MAX(Date)
FROM tbl  t1
WHERE Code = 1
GROUP BY t1.ID
HAVING MAX(Date) > (SELECT Date FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Code = 2)
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/484166)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`.

```
select *
from t 
where code = 1 and
      exists (select 1 from t t1 where t.id = t1.id and t.dt > t1.dt and t1.code=2)
```

Comment: just need to poke an `AND` in there

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
, max(date)
from table to
where to.code = 1
and exists (select 1 from table ti where ti.id = to.id AND ti.code = 2)
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

@vkp has the best answer.  But, here is an approach using window functions:

```
select t.id, t.code, t.dt
from (select t.*, min(case when code = 2 then dt end) over (partition by id) as dt_2
      from t
      where code in (1, 2)
     ) t
where t.code = 1 and dt_2 < dt;
```